# redirect subdomain to page unless other page is called

Tags: mod-rewrite

i am trying to redirect all subdomains with more than 2 letters :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]{2,})\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php?page=static&subject=%1 [L,QSA]
```

for example : `about.domain.com` to display content of `domain.com/?page=static&subject=about`
but the URL remains `about.domain.com` in the browser

as well as if you're on `about.domain.com` and requested another page on that domain ( all pages go through index.php?page=blablabla) you need to be redirected back to `domain.com/(whatever requested)`

Answer (score 0):

Same-domain internal rewrites can be done with the [P] ([proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html)) option.

If you need to reverse proxy a URL from the same virtual host config, you might be able to get away with a [P] rule, but if the domain of the internal request is from a different virtual host (or on a different box entirely) you probably need to look at a [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) config.

In either case you will need mod_proxy installed and enabled.